# React: filter state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to ask you for a little help.
I didn't know how to set the title for my problem. I'm new to React, Redux coding and I have this problem:
I have form for adding a new payment with Select  +  options. Options are generated from 'users' that I load from API, and store it in my redux store. The value of each option is user.id.
So: I want to set up the thing - when I select a user in Select form I want to show his pay info (in users table I have: mail, pass, ..., pay).
The payment should be inserted to payment table, where I have rows: id, user_id, date.
So my question is: How to read that 'pay' prop, in dependecy of user_id.

I would be really happy if someone could help me. 
Thank you.
Here is a code of my NewPayment.js file. Of course, It is still in progress mode :)

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {getAllUsers} from "../../store/actions/userActions";
import {getUserById} from "../../store/actions/userActions";

class NewPayment extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAllUsers();

    }

    state = {
        user_id: 0,
        date: new Date().getDate() + '/' + (new Date().getMonth()+1) + '/' + new Date().getFullYear(),
        pay: 0,
        id: 0,
    }


    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { users } = this.props.users;


        const newPayment = {
            date: this.state.date,
            user_id: this.state.user_id,
            pay: 
        };
        console.log(newPayment);

    }

    render() {

        const { users } = this.props.users;
        return (
            <div className='container dashboard'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h2>Nová platba</h2>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="user_id">User</label>
                        <select className="form-control" id="user_id" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option>Select an option</option>

                            { users.map(user => {
                                return (
                                    (user.pay>0) ? <option key={user.id} value={""+user.id+""
                                    }>{user.name + ' ' + user.lastname}</option> : ''



                                )
                            })}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="pay">Pay</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control"
                              disabled value=''
                            />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

NewPayment.propTypes = {
    getAllUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    users: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.user

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllUsers, getUserById })(NewPayment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your  constructor with the props first and then see if you can solve the other issues, else leave a comment.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {connect} from "react-redux";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import {getAllUsers} from "../../store/actions/userActions";
    import {getUserById} from "../../store/actions/userActions";

    class NewPayment extends Component {
     constructor(props){
    state = {
            user_id: 0,
            date: new Date().getDate() + '/' + (new Date().getMonth()+1) + '/' + new Date().getFullYear(),
            pay: 0,
            id: 0,
        }

    }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getAllUsers();

        }




        handleChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
            })
        }

        handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { users } = this.props.users;


            const newPayment = {
                date: this.state.date,
                user_id: this.state.user_id,
                pay: 
            };
            console.log(newPayment);

        }

        render() {

            const { users } = this.props.users;
            return (
                <div className='container dashboard'>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <h2>Nová platba</h2>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="user_id">User</label>
                            <select className="form-control" id="user_id" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                <option>Select an option</option>

                                { users.map(user => {
                                    return (
                                        (user.pay>0) ? <option key={user.id} value={""+user.id+""
                                        }>{user.name + ' ' + user.lastname}</option> : ''



                                    )
                                })}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="pay">Pay</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control"
                                  disabled value=''
                                />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }

    }

    NewPayment.propTypes = {
        getAllUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        users: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };


    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            users: state.user

        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllUsers, getUserById })(NewPayment);
```